# Proving $2^n -1 > \frac {n(17n-89)}{2}$ for all positive $n$ without induction

Tags: inequality

If $n$ is any positive integer then $2^n -1 > \frac {n(17n-89)}{2}$ is true . How to prove this inequality without induction?

Comment: You are safe till $n=5$, what happens after that?

Comment: What facts about $2^n$ do you know that don't require induction?

Comment: @Inceptio : Well,I basically use induction for $n≥8$ , verifying all the values upto 8 by computation,the method is quite laborious, this is why I want to find another method.

Comment: @SouvikDey: You can consider $\log_2a$ to avoid computation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll hide the induction in claims about

- how many ways there are to choose $k$ element subsets out of an $n$ element set
- how many subsets an $n$-element set has.

If $n>m+2$, then the number of ways to select $2$ out of $n$ objects and paint them blue, and afterwards select an arbitrary subset of the first $m$ non-blue objects and paint them red, is
$$ {n\choose 2}\cdot2^m.$$
This gives us one of $2^n-1$ nonempty sets of painted objects (actually, the set has $2\le k\le m+2$ elements) and each such subsets occurs with at most $m+2\choose 2$ different red/blue patterns. Hence
$$ 2^m\cdot{n\choose 2}\le {m+2\choose 2}\cdot (2^n-1)$$
or $$\frac{2^{m+1}}{(m+2)(m+1)}\cdot{n\choose 2}\le 2^n-1.$$
Since
$$\frac{n(17n-89)}2<\frac{n(17n-17)}2 =17\cdot\frac{n(n-1)}2$$
we find that
$$ \frac{n(17n-89)}2<2^n-1$$
if we can choose $m=11$ (as $\frac{2^{12}}{13\cdot12}=\frac{1024}{39}>17$).
So this solves the problem for all $n>13$, while the rest can be checked manually.

Comment: Beautiful proof , I must say , very beautiful.

Comment: @SouvikDey Well, "beautiful" is not what came to my mind. After all, there is a lot of wasting going on merely to get rid of that factor $17$ (otherwise one could simply say that there are less two-element subsets than non-empty subsets).

Comment: "otherwise one could simply say that there are less two-element subsets than non-empty subsets" , but it is a trivial statement isn't it , the waste doesn't matter 'cause it saves immense time that would be wasted in an induction proof, I carried out the induction proof,now have read your proof, this is why I said it is beautiful and also useful.

Answer (score 1):

You can try considering $$\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\frac{n^2}{2^n}=0$$

Answer (score 0):

**Fact $1$:** $2^n$ moves way faster than $n^2$, for $n \ge 4$

**Fact $2$:** $2^n$ moves way faster than $n^3$, for $n \ge 10$